# Помогите понять условие задания

Tags: c++, алгоритм

> Создать иерархию классов представляющих простое наследование. Базовый
>   класс – строка символов (char *). Производный класс – методы,
>   работающие с данными базового класса. Реализовать в производном классе
>   метод – поиска и удаления самого короткого слова в строке базового
>   класса

Где мне нужно искать и удалять слово? Я реализовал наследование, создается класс на основе базового. Я инициализировал базовый и производный. Теперь где мне нужно искать и удалять слово? В производном, в переменной производного, или в производном, в переменной базового? В задании написано: "в строке базового класса", мне нужно из производного произвести поиск и удаление в базовом, или это означает что я унаследовал переменную базового и теперь в производном должен это сделать в переменной производного?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class FirstClass {
    protected:
        char* str_value;
    public:
        //FirstClass() {}

        FirstClass(const char* value = ""):str_value(0) {
            set(value);
        }

        FirstClass(const FirstClass &obj):str_value(0) {
            set(obj.str_value);
        };

        ~FirstClass() {delete[] str_value;}

    void set(const char* value) {
        delete[] str_value;
        str_value = new char[strlen(value)+1];
        strcpy(str_value, value);
    }

    const char* get() const {
        return str_value;
    }
};

class SecondClass : public FirstClass {
    public:
        SecondClass(const char* str_value = "") : FirstClass (str_value) {}
    void findShortestWord()
    {
        str_value = "kokoko";
    }
 };

int main() {
    FirstClass F_object("aaaaaaaaaa");

    printf("\n%s", F_object.get());

    F_object.set("bbbbbbbbbb");

    printf("\n%s", F_object.get());

    FirstClass F_object2 = F_object;

    SecondClass S_object();

    printf("\n%s", F_object.get());

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Теперь создаете метод

```
class SecondClass : public FirstClass 
{
public:
    SecondClass(const char* str_value = "") : FirstClass (str_value) {}
    void findShortestWord()
    {
      //здесь работаем с str_value
    }
};
```

И работаете на прямую с полем `str_value`.

Но это не очень хорошо. Лучше скрыть это поле в `private`  и реализовать в базовом классе простейшие операции, например доступ по индексу, и так далее. А уже в производном классе можно реализовать более специфическую логику вроде поиска и удаления самого короткого слова. И методы производного класса будут использовать только функции базового.

Comment: я так и думал. спасибо

Comment: А обращаться к ней как FirstClass.str_value ? str_value не изменяет значение в базовом классе

Comment: Можно обращаться просто `str_value`, или `FirstClass::str_value`. У вас один класс и одно поле `str_value`. Производный класс как-бы состоит из двух частей: самого себя и базового класса.

Comment: пишу str_value = "kokoko"; и вывожу printf("\n%s", F_object.get());. На выводе старое значение базового класса

Comment: добавил текущий код в вопрос

Comment: У вас `str_value = "kokoko"` есть только в методе `findShortestWord` который не вызывается.

Comment: пора в отпуск))

Comment: Что за дела при вызове метода из main? expected unqualified-id before '.' token
Вызов SecondClass.findShortestWord(); точка с запятой везде стоит

Comment: Нельзя написать `SecondClass.findShortestWord()`. Это не имеет смысла. Нужно сначала создать объект типа `SecondClass` А потом у него вызывать метод. `SeconClass obj; obj.findShortestWord();` Без создания объекта можно вызывать только статические методы. И вызываются они так `SecondClass::findShortestWord()`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68998/discussion-between-anton-and-aaa).